# How to remove extra newline character from pipe delimted file except last new line of row?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, scripting

I have a sample file with below data

```
No|Name|sal  
1|abc|4500  
2|gkdjkh|554  
3|fgh  
cvb|678  
4|tyu|789  
5|ghl  
tyu|5677  
6|yyui  
tyui  
uui|780  
7|tpo|567
```

I need output data like below

```
No|Name|sal  
1|abc|4500  
2|gkdjkh|554  
3|fgh cvb|678  
4|tyu|789  
5|ghl tyu|5677  
6|yyui tyui uui|780  
7|tpo|567
```

Comment: you'll have to add what code you tried and explain how it is failing...

Comment: Thanks @WalterA ..but this solution is not working if I am adding newline in last field

Comment: @Tarun just defuted a partial solution I gave in a comment. It is hard to find any approach, I understand that you did not find a starting point for a solution. You can always use a while loop, pasing one line and using a lot of vars, but that would be a slow solution. `awk` is the right tool, but I tried to solve it without `awk`. I failed the challenge.

Comment: Suppose you have three lines: `a|b|c`, `d`, and `e|f|g`. Should the `d` be appended to the first line or is it part of the second?

Comment: If we have file with 3 fields with | delimiter , then this ",d," should be appended as part of first line.

Answer (score 0):

Perl instead of sed seems to work fine and better than sed in my tests:

```
$ perl -pe 's/^[0-9]+[|]/\0$&/g; s/\n/ /g; s/^\0/\n/g' file
No|Name|sal 
1|abc|4500 
2|gkdjkh|554 
3|fgh cvb|678 
4|tyu|789 
5|ghl tyu|5677 
6|yyui tyui uui|780 
7|tpo|567
```

Comment: this assumes `_` won't be part of input data.. for example `_cvb|678`... a better solution might be to rely on field separator alone.. `perl -pe 'while(!/\|.*\|/){chomp;$n=<>;$_ .= $n} s/ +/ /g'` ... the substitute is to deal with excess spaces as is present in OP's sample

Comment: @Sundeep Indeed, this method assumes that there is no _ in the data. What about using `\0` which keeps working fine? `perl -pe 's/^[0-9]+[|]/\0$&/g; s/\n/ /g; s/^\0/\n/g' file`

Comment: @Sundeep by the way i'am doing some tests by using `_` in data or even `_6` but keeps working good. I am not able to "break" my solution. The reason is the last expression `s/^_/\n/g` - The usage of `^` saves the game.

Comment: Thank You **George** & **Sundeep** for your quick response...I think this will specifically work for file having 3 fields only...What if we want to pass number of field as a parameter ?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou as I mentioned, try `_cvb|678` as 5th line in OP's input... also, your solution didn't have newline for last line when I checked... Tarun, you could try `perl -pe 'while(!/(.*\|.*){3}/){chomp;$n=<>;$_ .= $n} s/ +/ /g'` where you can use number of fields for `{3}`

Comment: @Sundeep Yes, with `_cvb|678` at 5th line solutuion breaks. I will switch my solution to use `\0` instead of `_`

Comment: @Sundeep and George...Both the solution will work if I am using numeric as first field. But If in case I receive alpha numeric as first field, it will not work.

Comment: @TarunPant 1)If the input data are not correct, solutions are also not correct. 2) In case of alpha chars is impossible for any solution to work. If all lines start with alphanumeric how a script will know which line has to be joined with previous one?

Comment: @TarunPant my solution depends only on delimiter, not on type of column data (unless data can have delimiter as well)... in any case, you need to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , especially understand that SO is about helping with code you already tried and got stuck

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution (based on processing each next line of the input file):

***rearrange_fields.awk*** script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{ FS="|" } 
{
    if (NR == 1) {print $0}  # print the first header line as is
    else {
        if (NF == 3) { print $0 }
        else { 
            while ((getline nl) > 0) {     # processing each next line
            if (nl !~ /^[0-9]+\|/) {   # if it's not a regular line (with starting order digit i.e. `1|`)
                    if (prepend) { 
                        $0 = prepend" "$0  # prepend the last partial line if exists
                    }
                    $0 = $0" "nl;          # append to previous line 
                    gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ",$0)  # remove redundant spaces
                } 
                else {
                    if (nl !~ /.+\|.+\|.+/) { # if a loop ends up with line which starts with order number 
                                              # but hasn't enough fields
                        prepend = nl
                        print $0
                    } 
                    else {
                        prepend = ""
                        print $0 RS nl        # next line is a regular valid line
                    } 
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Usage***:

```
awk -f rearrange_fields.awk yourfile
```

The output:

```
No|Name|sal  
1|abc|4500  
2|gkdjkh|554  
3|fgh cvb|678 
4|tyu|789  
5|ghl tyu|5677 
6|yyui tyui uui|780 
7|tpo|567
```

Comment: Thanks @Roman .but what if I have all 3 fields coming as string ?

Comment: @TarunPant, you did not mention that in your question. That seems like another case to play

Comment: How about the next 3 lines: `1|abc|45`, `00`, `2|gkdjkh|554` ?

Answer (score 0):

gawk-only solution using regex for `RS` and gawk-only `RT` built-in. (For a different number of fields, change `{2}` to be one less than the number of fields.)

```
$ gawk -v RS="[^|]+([|][^|]+){2}\n" '{ gsub("\n", " ", RT); print RT}' f
No|Name|sal 
1|abc|4500 
2|gkdjkh|554 
3|fgh cvb|678 
4|tyu|789 
5|ghl tyu|5677 
6|yyui tyui uui|780 
7|tpo|567
```

Comment: Thanks @jas . But this command is giving blank output when I am running it on server ..Any idea about this issue ?

Comment: It works on your local machine but not on the server?

Comment: Check the version (`awk --version`). This solution will only work with _gawk_, and only with gawk version __3.0__ or greater.

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.7  This is the version I have.

Comment: That version should be fine. Something different about the data between the two servers?

Comment: I have created same data file for both servers. But while running on server , it is exiting without giving any output . I have even tried running on online terminal , but there also , it is showing no result.

Comment: Below is the online terminal link where I tried   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_terminal_online.php

Comment: It works for me at that link. Is it possible that the file you have in the Unix environment has Windows/DOS line endings?

Comment: my bad...its working fine on portal..It doesn't have any carriage return. But apart from running it on local host . I have run it on 2 different servers. unluckily ,not working on both.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is suited for this question, but I found a solution with `sed` and `grep`.
A hard part is how to deal with a line without `|` delimiters. You can join these lines with the previous line using (the \d008 and \r are chars not in the input)

```
sed 's/^[^|]*$/\d008&\d008/' inputfile | tr '\n' '\r' |
   sed -r "s/\r\d008([^\d008]*)\d008/\1/g" |
   tr '\r' '\n'
```

Now we can join all lines to a line string (replacing the \n with a marker needed for the next `grep`), and get the substrings needed. Use -P for the special char `\r`.

```
sed 's/^[^|]*$/\d008&\d008/' inputfile | tr '\n' '\r' |
   sed -r "s/\r\d008([^\d008]*)\d008/\1/g" |
   grep -Po "([^|]*\|){2}[^|\r]*" |
   tr -d '\r'
```

Above solution is too slow for OP (and also ugly complex), but a lot faster than using a `while-loop`:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   # process header, determine nr of pipes
   if [ -z "${slashes}" ]; then           
      slashes=${line//[^|]}               
      n_slashes=${#slashes}               
      printf "%s\n" "${line}"             
      lastslashes=0                       
      continue
   fi
   # You have to print previous line when you have the required fields
   # and the next line has new fields
   new_slashes=${line//[^|]}
   n_new_slashes=${#new_slashes}
   if (( ${n_new_slashes} + ${lastslashes} > ${n_slashes} )); then
      printf "%s\n" "${last}"
      last="${line}"
      lastslashes=${n_new_slashes}
   else
      # Append new line to last one
      last="${last}${line}"
      ((lastslashes+=n_new_slashes))
   fi
done < inputfile
echo "${last}"
```

With the above prototype you can get inspired for an `awk` solution.

```
awk -F '|' 'NR==1 {
        nfields=NF;
        lastfields=0;
        print
        next
        }
   NF+lastfields-1 > nfields { print last;last=$0; lastfields=NF; next }
   {lastfields+=NF-1} # Concat two fields, so substract 1
   {last=last $0}
   END {print last}
   ' inputfile
```

Comment: Thanks Walter. Its working perfectly but taking too long to execute in case of large file.

Comment: When you want this faster (and you do not want awk/perl/C/python/..), you will need all info you have: Is the first column (except the header) always filled with numbers? Ascending? Has the last column also only digits (integers?) Are the newlines only in the second field?

Comment: I have multiple files to process with different number of fields.I am looking for a generic solution that can work for all files. Solution which you provided is a generic one and working irrespective of field data type. Only issue is that it's taking time with big files.  New lines can come in any of the field except first field. First column may contain alphanumeric characters.Last column data type may vary file to file.

Comment: I edited my solution and added a nice `awk`-script. The `awk` works fine, I hope it is fast enough for you. With my testfile it is 3 times faster than the original script with `sed` and `grep`.